# MSMQ message cannot be parsed to object

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, msmq

I've get some stange result when trying to get messages from a MSMQ - it looks like the message is corrupt. I just get xml exceptions when I try to parse it back to an object.

Here is what I'm trying to do.

I'm writing to a MSMQ from a webservice using this code

```
 MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["receiptQueue"]);
            {
                queue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new[] { typeof(Receipt) });
                Message msg = new Message();
                Receipt obj = new Receipt();
                obj.AlertId = alertId;
                obj.UserName = userName;
                obj.Version = version;
                obj.PC = pcName;
                msg.Body = obj;
                queue.Send(msg);
            }
```

The Receipt object I'm using is looks like this

```
  public class Receipt
{
    public Receipt()
    {
    }
    public int AlertId { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public string UserName  { get; set; }
    public string PC { get; set; }
}
```

In a windows service I'm trying to get the object from the queue.

Init queue

```
 MessageQueue receiptQueue = new MessageQueue(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["receiptQueue"]);
        receiptQueue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new[] { typeof(Receipt) });
        receiptQueue.ReceiveCompleted += new ReceiveCompletedEventHandler(ReceiptReceiver);
        receiptQueue.BeginReceive();
```

Handle the message

```
 private void ReceiptReceiver(object source, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs asyncResult)
    {
        Receipt receptObj = new Receipt();
        MessageQueue mq = (MessageQueue)source;
        Message mes =mq.EndReceive(asyncResult.AsyncResult);          
        try
        {    
            receptObj = (Receipt)mes.Body; //error happens here
            //Do logic
         }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          // ex handeling
        }
        mq.BeginReceive();
    }
```

I get the following info for the message after mq.EndReceive

[image: Message object]

It then goes to catch where the exception is "Root element is missing"

This is a message from the queue. It looks pretty well formatted.

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Receipt xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <AlertId>500</AlertId>
    <Version>2</Version>
    <UserName>jk9c</UserName>
    <PC>aasudv211</PC>
</Receipt>
```

Any suggestions to what I'm doing wrong?

/Birger

Comment: What is the message in your MSMQ? If you had a massage on hand you would not what went wrong serialization or deserialization of your MSMQ.

Comment: I've added a message from the queue.. It looks well formatted

Answer (score 1):

Found the error.. It was a very simple and very stupid mistake.
I assigned the queue to a wrong formatter an other place in the code.

So I had

```
 receiptQueue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new[] { typeof(Receipt) });
```

and

```
 receiptQueue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new[] { typeof(AlertMessage) });
```

After I removed the last all is working well.